# CSV Download from a custom pop up

Tags: extension, php, smarty, csv, custom

I have a function that lists score for a dog:

```
<h3>Your Dog's Scores</h3>
{crmButton href="#" class="button-name" title="Download CSV" icon="icon-class-name"}Download CSV{/crmButton}
<table border='1' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='5'><tr class="crm-entity" id="Scores" style='border-bottom: 1px solid black'><th>Registered Name</th><th>Event</th><th>Level</th><th>Stream</th><th>Score</th><th>Max Points</th><th>Pass</th></td></tr>
{*{crmAPI var='dogs' entity='RegisteredDogs' action='get' contact_id = $contactid} *}
{foreach from=$scores key=arrayIndex item=score}
  <tr>
  <td>{$score->DogName}</td>
  <td>{$score->Event}</td>
  <td>{$score->LevelDescript}</td>
  <td>{$score->Stream}</td>
  <td>{$score->Score}</td>
  <td>{$score->MaxPoints}</td>
  <td>{$score->Pass}</td>
  </tr>
{/foreach} 

</table>
```

This works really well.  The pop-up window shows the scores and lists them out.  The issue is I'm being asked if I can export the displayed data as a CSV file.  I see on the top bar that there is a 'print' icon - is there a 'Download' option available?  My second option was to use a separate button (as you can see the crmButton on the second line).

The array $scores has the results from a SQL query in the PHP (above is the smarty template code).
Is there an easy way to add the csv download option?
Can I call a function with the href in the button?  Perhaps I just need to write a php function to do this?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm intrigued by these tests; do the dogs write essays or is it multiple-choice? How do the dogs hold their pencils? And how can you read their handwriting? Or is the test administered via computer? Can the dogs touch-type or is there bark-to-text recognition software? Perhaps you could recruit the dogs with the highest scores to write code for you?

Comment: LOL that made my day.  We are the largest scent detection association in Canada.  We are a non-profit that sanctions sport scent detection events :)  So we register dogs and handlers and keep track of their scores, awarding titles when they achieve certain levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I'm not barking up the wrong tree, but could you pawsibly try [SearchKit](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/searching/searchkit/what-is-searchkit/)? It's a doggone helpful tool that can render your table without any of that custom Smarty code (which can be ruff to maintain), and it has a built-in "Download Spreadsheet" action to fetch and retrieve CSV, XLSX, or ODS.

Bone Appétit!

Comment: I did look at it but the SQL is too complex for it (I think).  It has a couple of joins to other custom entities created by my custom extensions.

Comment: ... from civicrm_dog_scores
    inner join civicrm_registered_dogs ON civicrm_dog_scores.DogId = civicrm_registered_dogs.id
    inner join civicrm_contact ON civicrm_contact.id = civicrm_registered_dogs.contact_id
    inner join civicrm_trial_levels ON civicrm_dog_scores.Rules = civicrm_trial_levels.Id
    where DogId=".$this->_id." ORDER by Event

Comment: I also didn't find a SAVE CSV for the results pulled in from the Search.

Comment: If you retrofit xml for those tables then you can generate BAO/DAO and you get all the magic of API4 and SearchKit. https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/database/schema-definition/  https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/#generate-entity

Comment: Right, SearchKit can easily handle a query like that as long as you've got up-to-date metadata describing all the field specs and FKs. The download action is available in the "Actions" dropdown just above the results table in SearchKit.